# How can I tag code as generated

Tags: .net, code-generation

Is it any best practice to tag .net generated code?

What I want to achieve is following:

- Debugger step by default not inside the property or method
- Metrics are not calulated for those classes/members

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for the first - attributes (`[DebuggerStepThrough]` being the most important for your question); some useful ones here:

```
[DebuggerStepThrough, DebuggerHidden, DebuggerNonUserCode]
[CompilerGenerated] // arguably untrue...
```

Not sure about the second question.

Comment: I'm with mark on this - If you don't like the how the code metrics are being evaluated on your generated code maybe you need to adjust your templates?

Answer (score -1):

You might consider using [Postsharp](http://www.postsharp.org/) to manipulate the code once it is compiled.